# Отображение и обработка данных в связанных таблицах на фронтенде, при наличие очень большого числа этих данных

Tags: java, delphi, spring, gui, frontend

Предыстория вопроса (чтобы лучше понимать мою ситуацию)

Внедряю на работе Java. Фактически занимаюсь только бэкендом, пишу на Spring всякие автоматические фоновые сервисы, без UI. А вообще контора пишет на Delphi.

Сейчас понадобилось сделать UI для сервиса, причем в браузере. Фактически UI должен представлять собой 2 связанные 1-M таблицы со следующими требованиями:

1. Данных много - очень много, полный фетчинг лучше не делать - идеально быстро отобразить несколько строчек (видимых на  экране), и потом их асинхронно подгружать.
2. Переключение курсора на другую строчку в родительской таблице должно обновлять данные в дочерней (они связаны по ключевому полю/полям)
3. Код в какой-то момент времени должен знать, где стоит курсор в этих таблицах и обрабатывать эти данные

На Delphi через AnyDac (или раньше через BDE) это реализовывалось через `TQuery`, `TDataSource`, `TDBGrid` - и через связывание дочернего `TQuery` через родительский `TDataSource` - все работало быстро за счет ленивого фетчинга.

Посоветуйте правильное решение/библиотеку, как написать такое UI, если бэкенд - Java Spring. Писать свой велосипед не хочется, вероятно есть решение для таких задач.

P.S: лучше всего на JS/HTML5, либо на клиенте - Angular, либо на сервере - Velocity, Thymeleaf. Использовать Vaadin или JavaFX не хочется.